# Publishing to local maven repo using gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

So, I have two projects A and B. B is dependent on A and A is a library which builds a jar file.

A is configured to push the built jar to artifactory and B pulls it from artifactory. I am trying to understand if there is a way for A to push its built jar to local repo i.e. $HOME/.gradle and to push to artifactory when given artifactoryPublish. At the same time have B check the version locally and if the local version is latest than artifactory, then use the local built library.

How can this be done in grade, using build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can push '**A**' to your local maven repository in `~/.m2` by applying the `maven` plugin and run `gradle install`. Afterwards you can '**B**' let resolve it from there by adding the local maven repository to its repository definition:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I need something more subtle. By default when B resolves A using gradle, it puts A library under $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/...Thats where I want my locally built jar file to go. Not sure how easy is that.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for this in gradle. The `~/.gradle/caches` directory is really just a cache in gradle. means that you shouldn't tinker with these folders manually.